# Google Earth Engine - error when exporting table

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, error, table

I'm trying to export a frequency histogram table of a classified image for a region.

```
function country (image) {var c = image.reduceRegion({
  geometry: image.geometry(),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
}); return ee.Feature(c.select(['classification']))}

// export function
function export_table (table, description, date) { 
  var em = Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(table),
    description: region+'_'+description+'_'+date,
    folder: region,
});return em}
```

But I get the error: Error: Invalid argument: 'collection' must be a `FeatureCollection`.

I've set the FeatureCollection in the export function, so I don't know what's happening here.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/582da4a11433f1645b359b8ae2086c86

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `collection: ee.FeatureCollection(table)` with `collection: em`

and setting `var em` to `ee.FeatureCollection(table)`

I'm using the [GGE - Exporting Data](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting) as reference. Under exporting to Drive.

> To export a FeatureCollection to your Drive account, use Export.table.toDrive(). For example:

```
// Make a collection of points.
var features = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(30.41, 59.933), {name: 'Voronoi'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-73.96, 40.781), {name: 'Thiessen'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(6.4806, 50.8012), {name: 'Dirichlet'})
]);

// Export the FeatureCollection to a KML file.
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: features,
description:'vectorsToDriveExample',
fileFormat: 'KML'
});
```

> Note that the output format is specified as KML to handle geographic data (SHP would also be appropriate for exporting a table with geometry). To export just a table of data, without any geographic information, export features with null geometry in CSV format. The following demonstrates using Export.table.toDrive() to get the results of a potentially long running reduction:

Answer (score 0):

I tried yours and still code the same error, so instead I tried this and it worked.

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(May_2023), // Convert geometry to a feature collection if necessary
  description: 'exported_geometry', // Name of the exported file
  fileFormat: 'SHP' // Specify the export format (GeoJSON, Shapefile, etc.)
});
```